# How to get Document ID by using encoded edit link of that document using rest api in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, document-id

How to get Document ID by using encoded edit link of that document using REST API in SharePoint online?

Link of site `/:b:/s/SiteName/EZMojxE1NqNGgMljzTBZSSoBYOzeQJoW48yYm7WWBwUZcw`

I am trying:

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Site Name/EZMojxE1NqNGgMljzTBZSSoBYOzeQJoW48yYm7WWBwUZcw')/ListItemAllFields?$select=ID
```

It showing file does not exits but file is there in the document library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetFileByUrl` instead of `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` API:

```
{SiteUrl}/_api/web/GetFileByUrl(@url)/ListItemAllFields?@url='{SharingLinkUrl}'
```

Got hint from [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6293) article.

[image]

Comment: Thanks i got my output @KalpeshVaghela

Comment: If my answer did help to you then please mark this as answer so that it can be helpful to other in community